# Apache, php, maven and me—pemissions…

Tags: apache-2.2, php, permissions, unix

I have setup a local Apache2, with PHP and mysql. I wrote a maven build script to deploy my page on that local server. All that is working fine except for one thing:

When I instruct maven to clean up the page, means deleting all files, it runs in an permission problem, because maven must not delete Files and Directories created by php.

I have created a group called »web«. »Me« and »www-data« are both members of that group. After all the files are installed, means copied to the right location, maven runs two little commands: `chown -R me:web www-dir` and `chmod -R 777 www-dir`, and everything works fine.

Running the Website makes the PHP create files and Directories with this permissons: `drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data` and maven (or me) are not allowed to delete those files. Trying to run `chmod` and `chown` gives the same permission error.

How can I fix that without using the magic »sudo-power«?

Greetings philipp

Comment: I think you should be member of `www-data` group and have `drwxrwxr-x` permissions on `www-dir`. The problem will be solved.

Comment: I added myself to »www-data«, run: »chown -R me:www-data www-dir« but it still throws an error when trying to delete…

Comment: Apache will reset permissions and the owner:group to `www-data:www-data` where the group has no `-w-` write permissions. So if `www-dir` dir has `drwxr-xr-x  www-data:www-data` permissions, then you won't be able to write or delete files since the group has no `write` permissions. The group has only `read + execute` permissions.

Comment: Your are absolutely right. The permissions are reseted exactly as you say and consequently I cannot delete the files. But how can I work around that?

Comment: You can use `umask` to set the default permissions on the directory tree. `umask` instructs the kernel to remove bits that will not be set. So  `umask 002 www-dir`  will set `www-dir` to `drwxrwxr-x` permissions. Hope it helps